# jQuery which eq class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have list of items

```
<li><span class="glyphicon-remove glyphicon removeAnswerCount" onclick="removeAnswer($(this));"></span></li>
<li><span class="glyphicon-remove glyphicon removeAnswerCount" onclick="removeAnswer($(this));"></span></li>
<li><span class="glyphicon-remove glyphicon removeAnswerCount" onclick="removeAnswer($(this));"></span></li>
<li><span class="glyphicon-remove glyphicon removeAnswerCount" onclick="removeAnswer($(this));"></span></li>
<li><span class="glyphicon-remove glyphicon removeAnswerCount" onclick="removeAnswer($(this));"></span></li>
```

and function

```
function removeAnswer(that) {
  console.log(that.parent().eq()); <-- I need know which element is clicked
  that.parent().remove();
}
```

Do you know how I can read `eq` of the item in function `removeAnswer` ? I cant pass 2nd value in function because this is a part of my main script

I need this

```
console.log(that.parent().eq());
```

Comment: Why you didn't bind your function to class?

Comment: May be `$('li').indexOf(that.parent())`

Comment: indexOf dont work but I need something like this

Comment: `$('li').index(that.parent())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function removeAnswer(that) {
  console.log($(".glyphicon-remove").index(that))
}
```

If you click the 4th answer, this will print out `3` because index() returns the zero-based index of `that` within the collection of `.glyphicon-remove` elements.

Demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/2bxc62tx/

Answer (score 3):

This way you can detect which item will be removed (I have added `id`s to `li` elements to demonstrate):

```js
function removeAnswer(that) {
  console.log(that.parent().attr('id'));
  that.parent().remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="one"><span class="glyphicon-remove glyphicon removeAnswerCount" onclick="removeAnswer($(this));">1</span></li>
<li id="two"><span class="glyphicon-remove glyphicon removeAnswerCount" onclick="removeAnswer($(this));">2</span></li>
<li id="three"><span class="glyphicon-remove glyphicon removeAnswerCount" onclick="removeAnswer($(this));">3</span></li>
<li id="four"><span class="glyphicon-remove glyphicon removeAnswerCount" onclick="removeAnswer($(this));">4</span></li>
<li id="five"><span class="glyphicon-remove glyphicon removeAnswerCount" onclick="removeAnswer($(this));">5</span></li>
```

Comment: I cant do this, I have other button to add answers but this add to all 20 questions I realy need index

Answer (score 1):

You can use `index` method.

```
function removeAnswer(that) {
    console.log(that.parent().index());
    //that.parent().remove();
}
```